# Github, how to search content of comments in code history version?

Tags: github

Just as the title tells, in github, how can I search based on the content of  comments in code history version.

I have tried `in:comments` but this only returns the related comments in issues.

Comment: What platform do you want to use to search? If you are in a linux command line you could simply grep from the history. Do you need your results to look pretty or do you just need to find something?

Comment: Hi harmonica141, I just use mac, before that I though it may just easy to search on the search bar of website. Thanks I will try it.